# Criando links dentro das views PHP

Tags: php, html

Estou estudando a arquitetura MVC assistindo vídeos e procurando exemplos na Internet, consegui implementar as três camadas e mapear as rotas do meu sistema, porém me surgiu a dúvida de como devo criar links dentro da views. Não sei se devo apenas chamar os arquivos diretamente, ou se devo utilizar os controllers e o sistema de rotas para isso.

1 - Criando links diretos dos arquivos

```
<li style="margin-top: -20px;"><a href="../login.php">Entrar</a></li>
```

2 - Por rota (Creio que não seja a forma correta mas funciona no meu caso)

```
<li style="margin-top: -20px;"><a href="login">Entrar</a></li>
```

3 - utilizando controller (Não sei como fazer, devo instânciar um controller dentro do href ?)

```
<li style="margin-top: -20px;"><a href="     ">Entrar</a></li>
```

Class Action

```
<?php
namespace SON\Controller;

class Action{

    protected $view;
    protected $action;

    public function __construct(){
      $this->view = new \stdClass;
   }

    public function render($action, $layout=true){
        $this->action = $action;
        if($layout == true && file_exists("../App/Views/Template/layout.phtml")){

            switch ($action) {
                case "login":
                    include_once '../App/Views/Template/layoutLogin.phtml';
                    break;
                case "sobre":

                    break;
                case "home":
                include_once '../App/Views/Template/layoutHome.phtml';
                    break;
                default:
                include_once '../App/Views/Template/layout.phtml';
            }

        }
        else{
            $this->content();
        }
    }

    public function content(){
        $atual = get_class($this);
        $singleClassName = strtolower(str_replace("App\\Controllers\\","",$atual));
        include_once '../App/Views/'.$this->action.'.phtml';
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: como está o template principal projeto? dentro dele você tem algum código para renderizar as outras views ou em cada view dentro do delas tem html head body etc?

Comment: Fiz uma classe Action responsável por esse processo, vou actualizar o código

Comment: ainda ficou a duvida, dentro desses arquivos layoutHome, layoutLogin você tem a estrutura completa de um html?  você carrega as views dentro do body do seu template padrão ou cada layout desse tem um html completo?

Comment: em cada um desses layout tenho uma estrutura HTML com head, cabeçalho e  footer, o conteúdo das paginas ficam em outros arquivos, para chama-lo utilizo <?php echo $this>content();?>

Comment: O formato do numero dois é o ideal, deve seguir utilizando ele sempre que conseguir!

Comment: Mas analisando como você construiu a estrutura de views e template vejo que ou você tem mais de um tema no sistema ou não está sabendo criar um template base! Acredito que o certo é dentro do body do template base você carregar o seu content da pagina clicada! Existem diversas formas de se fazer isso aconselho você dar uma googlada para ter exemplos de sistema de rotas para se basear, mas a forma mais fácil é usando um `$_GET` você teria que adaptar seu código mas pegaria o parâmetro pela url mesmo Ex: esse seria seu link para home `/index.php?page=home`.

Comment: Criei alguns layouts diferentes pois no caso há necessidade, mas de fato não sei muito bem como criar um template, obrigado pela ajuda vou pesquisar mais sobre

Comment: depende da estrutura do seu site.